# Select and delete outdated duplicate records?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a Grading db, looks like this:

```
StudentId | SubjectCode | Grade | DateApproved

Student1 | SUBJ1234 | - | 30-3-2012<br/>
Student1 | SUBJ1234 | 2.25 | 31-3-2012<br/>
Student1 | SUBJ45678 | 2.00 | 31-2012
```

If you'll notice, there's an outdated duplicate with a blank grade (represented by `"-"`).

I'd like to select all blank grades from the db THAT HAS A DUPLICATE BUT MORE RECENT item, so I can delete them.

How do I do this in `SQL (MySql 5.5)` ?

Comment: **WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM yourTableName as t1 
   WHERE t1.Grade = "-" 
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM yourTableName as t2 
                     WHERE t1.StudentId = t2.StudentId 
                         AND t1.SubjectCode = t2.SubjectCode 
                         AND t1.DateApproved < t2.DateApproved
                 )
```

The code basically selects all fields from your table, that have the grade set as `-` and there is a record that has the same `StudentId` and `SubjectCode` and a higher (newer) `DateApproved`.

EDIT: In case you want the "new" record to have a defined `Grade` (other than `-`), add: `AND t2.Grade != '-'` after the last condition in the inner query, before the closing bracket.